# Use Any() and Count() in Dynamic Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql, dynamic-linq

I am trying to write dynamic Linq Library query to fetch record on condition,
Customers who has order count is greater than 3 and ShipVia field equal 2.

Below is my syntax what i have tried.

```
object[] objArr = new object[10];
objArr[0] = 1;
IQueryable<Customer> test = db.Customers.Where("Orders.Count(ShipVia=2)", objArr);
```

and

```
IQueryable<Customer> test = db.Customers.Where("Orders.Any(ShipVia=2).Count()", objArr);
```

But both are not working. In second query Any returns true so it won't work with Count.
Suggest  me a way to implement this.

Comment: Maybe it should be "Orders.Count(ShipVia==2)"

Comment: @boca: inner query will be converted directly to SQL, I guess, where condition operator is =, not ==

Answer (score 2):

If you HAVE to use Dynamic Linq, your query should look like that:

```
db.Customers.Where("Orders.Count(ShipVia == 2) > 3");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this.

```
IQueryable<Customer> test = db.Customers.Where(c => c.Orders.Where(o => o.ShipVia ==2).Count() >2);
```

Comment: Actually i am using Linq Dynamic extension library. So i have to pass string based query inside Where(). And I can't convert this lambda expression to string based query.

Comment: How about db.Customers.Where("Orders.Count(ShipVia=2) > 3")

Answer (score 1):

```
var grp = db.Customers.Where("ShipVia=2").GroupBy("ShipVia");

var test = from a in grp
             where a.Count() > 3
             select a.Key;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<Customer> test = 
    from c in db.Customers
    from o in c.Orders
    where o.ShipVia == 2 // NOTE you need == not = for compare
    group c by c into grp
    select new {customer = grp.key, ordercount = grp.Count() };
```

Untested but I believe this should do it all in one statement, assuming Orders are a collection within Customer.

Note that your single = in your where clause is very dangerous as it'll assign 2 to all shipvias instead of test (==)